# p5.js code does not run while 2 images are being loaded

Tags: javascript, drawing, p5.js

Basically what it sounds like, whenever I try to load in a single image it works perfectly fine, but when I attempt two it gives me an undefined variable error. Both images are in the same folder and are uploaded correctly.

Code (working):

```js
let img
function preload() {
  img = loadImage('images/mario.png');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  //this loads in mario

  image(img, 0, 350, 50, 50)
}
```

Code (not working):

```js
let img;
let img2;
function preload() {
  img = loadImage('images/mario.png');
}

function preload() {
  img2 = loadImage('images/level.png');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  //this loads in mario
  image(img2, 0, 0, 400, 400)  
  image(img, 0, 350, 50, 50)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can only have one [`preload`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/preload) callback function. `prelaod` is an ansynchronous function that is called before `setup`:

```js
let img;
let img2;
function preload() {
  img = loadImage('images/mario.png');
  img2 = loadImage('images/level.png');
}
```